# Correct way to use multiple filters in an elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I've managed to put together some fairly complex queries (for instance, for generating a heatmap from data), and thought I understood the query syntax, but it appears that I don't.

I'm trying to return the data which matches the following criteria:

- Event is MyEvent
- Has a field called "MyField"
- Has a timestamp from less than one minute ago.

This is what I've tired, it doesn't return an error, but also doesn't return the correct results:

```
{
"query" :
{
    "filtered":
    {
        "query":
        {
            bool:
            {
                must:
                    [
                        { match: { "event": "UpdateTitle" } }
                    ]
            }
        },
        "filter" :
        {
            "range" :
            {
                "@timestamp" :
                {
                    "gt" : "now-1m"
                }
            }
        }
        ,
        "filter" :
        {
            "exists" :
            {
                "field" : "Lobby"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Obviously I've tried reading the documentation, but it's examples are generally only snippets rather than full queries, and the use of identically named queries and filters makes them incredibly confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to produce the effect I desired, hopefully it's using filters over queries:

```
{
"query" :
{
    "filtered":
    {
       "filter" : 
       {
            bool:
            {
                must:
                    [
                        { "term": { "event.raw": "MyEvent" } },
                        { "range" : { "@timestamp" : { "gt" : "now-1m" } } },
                        { "exists" : { "field" : "MyField" } }
                    ]
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

}